# ごほーし meaning? 18+?

Tags: grammar, meaning

ごほーし meaning? 18+?
I know that's lewd vocabulary but I dont what does it mean?

Answer (score 4):

The word itself is nothing lewd. It's an intentional nonstandard spelling of ご奉仕【ほうし】 "serve / service to *somebody*". ご is the polite/humble prefix that usually doesn't translate into anything in English.

For the connotation of using the long vowel mark instead of う, see:

- [Why is it spelled やっほー instead of やっほう?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62676/7810)
- [ー vs small kana vs long kana for writing long vowels](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15062/7810)